# Android Paste onClick

Tags: java, android, onclick

pretty simple question here but I cant seem to find anything. Anyway, There is a game on android and with a keyboard you can enter a cheat id like to use(personal use not uploading to market) . Well I created a static button that remains on-top of all activities. Id like to just click my button and have it paste the word to the game so the cheat will be entered. Anyway to paste onclick? I cant see this being hard

Comment: how to basically paste Onlick.. I cant find any examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make other apps behave in a different way than they do as it violates the whole sandboxing idea of android (unless of course the app itself allows it in some way or another) .

What you can do is to copy the content to the clipboard , and allow the user to paste it anywhere he can .

More info about it here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

There might be root solution , but like many root operations , i really lacks this knowledge of how to do it.

Comment: I mean to open the keyboard, onclick.. have it type on the nearest focused edit text, or text box

Comment: i tried... InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

Comment: the only thing that you can do is to implement your own soft keyboard , and add there a button for pasting .